# Why this http request no respond?

Tags: android, httprequest

I set the following Http request. but Why this HTTP request no respond?

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
Log.d("click","click");
        client.get("http://www.baidu.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                Log.d("response",response);
                //System.out.println(response);
            }
        });
```

Anyone's help is very thanksful.

Comment: implement an onFailure method and print out response string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement other `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` methods and see what happens:

```
client.get("http://www.baidu.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() 
{
    static final String TAG = "AsyncHttpResponseHandler";
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Success: " + response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failure: " + response, e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Finish");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer to create an AsyncTask ans start a URLConnection.
See this thread for more info: [How to add AsyncTask in an HttpURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790324/how-to-add-asynctask-in-an-httpurlconnection)